# OpenCvSharp throws DllNotFoundException

Tags: opencv, dllnotfoundexception

I have similiar problem as was presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8227298/problems-with-dllimport-in-c-sharp-under-windows-7-x32), but with opencv_imgproc231.dll (opencv_core231.dll is loaded correctly in my case).

I installed OpenCV 2.3.1 and set environment variable PATH to foldres in "vc9\bin" folder. I added all OpenCvSharp dlls to references. When I run my c# program, it loads opencv_core231.dll correctly, but opencv_imgproc231.dll cant find (is in tha same directory as all opencv dlls). I tried copy opencv dlls to folder where is executable file, but it showed same error.

I did all what he did - C++ red. pack. 2008, 2010SP1, set PATHs, copy openCV dlls to folder, where is executable file - but nothing works, still DllNotFoundException for opencv_imgproc231.dll.

I have VS2008 and Windows 7 32bit. 
My program contains only one row: "IplImage image = new IplImage(128, 128, BitDepth.U8, 1);".

Thanks for any advice.

Pavel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved it. There is problem in precompiled openCV DLL. So if you have similar problem, recompile openCV and it will work. I dont why, but precompiled opencv_imgproc230.dll has 1579008 bytes and my recompiled opencv_imgproc230.dll has 1568768 bytes, but it works.

Comment: Just FYI: Length differences can be because source flie paths are stored in the DLL and that usually changes between builds on different computers. The binary might be identical anyway. (But not in your case. I'm just saying don't rely on it...)

Answer (score 1):

I found this issue at google code http://code.google.com/p/opencvsharp/issues/detail?id=97

add *tbb.dll* (from *opencv/build/common/tbb*) to PATH or same folder of the executable works for me :)